# Connection Refused to Presto Python API from Postgres Server running locally

Tags: postgresql, presto, trino

I am running a Postgres server locally using an [app](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/) and am using the `prestodb.dbapi` for Python to query my database.

The code I am using is

```
conn = presto.Connection(host="localhost", port=5433, user=USER)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SHOW catalogs")
cur.fetchall()
```

But right around the line where I execute the code "SHOW catalogs", my program fails with an error message

"requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))"

I've tried using different apps and different ports but no luck so far. This error occurs no matter what SQL I try. I'm using another app TablePlus, to see my Postgres database and it has all the data I need. However, the Presto connection to the database, isn't working. Can you help me spot the bug?

Comment: For troubleshooting like this, if you find SO's question-answer format insufficient, I recommend you ask on `#troubleshooting` channel on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).

Answer (score 0):

> "requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))"

This means the client could not connect to Presto server.

How are you running Presto? The easiest way to get started would be to run the docker container image:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --name presto prestosql/presto:334
```